# Processo em node sendo encerrado sozinho

Tags: node.js, loop, websocket, processo

Estou utilizando a documentação em node da blinktrade para receber notificações de depósitos em bitcoins, porem o processo polling está sendo encerrado sozinho dessa forma interrompendo o funcionamento do meu sistema, como posso resolver isso ? [image: Erro code-0]

```
const BlinkTradeWS = require('blinktrade').BlinkTradeWS;
const blinktrade = new BlinkTradeWS({
    brokerId: 11,
});

blinktrade.connect().then(() => {

    return blinktrade.login({
      username: "<>",
      password: "<>",
    });

  }).then((profile) => {

    blinktrade.onDepositRefresh(function(deposit) {
        console.log(deposit);
      });

});
```

Comment: Sem algum código é quase impossível precisar o motivo da dificuldade.

Comment: Eu nunca usei o blinktrade por isso não vou formular uma resposta. Mas esse erro ocorre porque uma das funções é assíncrona e está empacotada com [`Promisse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) e essa função pode emitir um erro, em caso de time-out, que não foi tratado em seu código. Coloque um `catch()` ou no bloco de conexão ou no bloco do login.